# Refresh of darksky JSON Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a little Chrome Extension for private use, that shows me (for now) the current weather data for certain locations using darksky API. 
The idea is for the weather data to appear in the chrome extension popup, once you click on the icon. 
My code is as follows:

popup.html:

```
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
       height: 300px;
       width: 600px;
    }
</style>

         <title>Good Morning!</title>
         <script src="static/jquery.js"></script>
         <script src="static/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
```

scripts.js:

```
$.getJSON(
    "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[API KEY]/52.075,-0.7333?exclude=minutely,daily,alerts,flags,hourly,daily&units=si",
    {},
    function(data) {


        document.getElementById("Walthamstow").innerHTML =
'Time: ' + JSON.stringify(data.currently.time)+ "<br>" +
'Summary: ' + JSON.stringify(data.currently.summary)+"<br>" +
'Temperature: '+ JSON.stringify(data.currently.temperature)+' \xB0'+'C'
    }
);
```

Sadly, the data does not refresh. At least the time stamp should refresh almost every second. But no matter how often I click the icon, it shows the same data. However, if I run the darksky request URL in a seperate Tab, it then updates the data in the popup as well.

Comment: The popup has its own document so if you want to update the currently opened page you need a content script which you can also run with chrome.tabs.executeScript in the popup.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I thought it would re-create (and run all affiliated scripts) the pop-up every time I reopen it (by clicking the icon). I guess that is not the case? Do you know if there is a script that just says "When the popup window gets opened, rerun all scripts?"

Comment: When you open the popup, the scripts are run *every time*. There is no memory of the contents of the popup kept when it is not displayed. One possibility is that the response data for your request is being cached by the browser. This would cause what is displayed to be the same each time the popup is opened. Use one of the standard methods for defeating browser caching (e.g. add an incrementing number in an fake/unused parameter in the query portion of the URL, which changes with each request).

Comment: It is bad practice to use untrusted data (e.g. that you get from an external source) as part of what you use to change content using `.innerHTML`. You should create the HTML structure and make changes using `.textContent`. Given that you've already loaded jQuery, that would be `.text()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information and feedback. I will do my best to address both :)